# Online PDF to Offline version

Tags: open-source, pdf

Afternoon All

Needing a bit of help regarding my study material and what software can do what I need.

I am going on holiday in 2 days and when I get back I have an exam, so I want to do some study while away. I have purchased my study materials and have both a hard back copy of my text book and a login to an online version.

Sadly after looking at the costs to get wifi while on holiday (24 Euros a day), I can't use the online version (And the hard back will just get wet through round the pool).

So I want to be able to convert the online book to an offline version.

When viewing online it looks like the book is embeded in a frame, if I try print and save as PDF it only copies the visible page and doesn't get the rest of the pages in the frame.

Is there any software out there that can help?

Other than this I will be manually viewing each page, taking a screen shot and then scrolling down (800 pages in the book)

*When viewing online the sections are split into chapters and only 1 chapter visible at once

Thanks

Comment: As we cannot take a look at the sources, this is hard to answer. But take a look at [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/), which can deal with a lot of formats.

Comment: Different browsers deal with frames and iframes differently when printing. Try both Firefox and Chrome, maybe even IE or Edge if you are on a Windows machine.  Something I've done in the past to deal with similar was to use a Linux machine and the X windows "highlight to select/copy and middle click to paste" feature to copy an  entire book that was being served up by a terrible publisher's site.  You may also get "more"/less restricted access to the content if you use an assistive technologies browser, plugin, or program like JAWS.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, i have been looking at the code on the website and the site obviously wants to make it hard to copy the pages. They have set up different page containers for each sheet, which must be triggered when scrolling up and down. I will be going down the route of print screen each page